# Teradata Large Table Partitioning or Split into multiple parts

Tags: query-performance, teradata

We have a large table (4 Terabytes) in Teradata. For compliance reasons, we need to keep 13 months worth of data. However, for querying, we may only need one month worth of data (300GB). I have already added partitioning on a Timestamp column for a day interval. But I was wondering if I could split the table into 2 parts like below; would it help in query performance?

```
Table1 -- Contains data for last 30 days
Table2 -- Contains data older than a month but newer than 13 months
```

Comment: As long as you get partition elimination/pruning (based on your WHERE-condition on the timestamp column) read performance will not improve. But if you got additional indexes on the table you might implement them only on the 30 day table, saving 90% of the index space.

Comment: It makese sense. Thanks.